# How does performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: work?

Tags: ios, release, retain, retaincount, performselector

I have found that after calling `[self performSelector:@selector(method1:) withObject:self.tableView afterDelay:3];` that `self.tableView`'s `retainCount` changes? Why?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the retain could of your table view would be incremented because calling `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` retains the parameter so that it isn't gone when the method finally is executed. Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Hi,Rickay,Thank you very much! Now,i know this problem.
When calling `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`,will retain the parameter.When `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` finished, will release the parameter,so，in the end ,the parameter's retain count is no change! Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct. Glad to hear you straightened it out! Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! If someone's answer helped you, be sure to accept it; this way people know what works and what doesn't. Happy Stackoverflow-ing!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to worry about it - tableView will be retained while the selector is waiting to be executed and then automatically released again after it has executed. This won't cause leaks or crashes.

Comment: Hi,Nick Lockwood,thank you very much! You are right! I have tested it  just! But i have a new question！that is `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`,What the Modes is ? How to use? Can you explain it for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: inModes controls what priority it gets in the run loop. The run loop is basically a queue of stuff that the iPhone has to do every 60th of a second. It includes stuff like handle touch inputs, make network calls, fire timers, redraw the screen etc. When you say performSelectorAfterDelay you are adding another thing that the OS has to keep track of in its run loop. The mode controls how it prioritises that against its other tasks. The default value is fine for most purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have know more about this question from your answer.